# How to filter objects by ignoring upper and lower case letter django

Tags: python, django, filter, backend

recently I started learning django and I have several questions. And one of them has relationship with __icontains.

`Company.objects.filter(name__icontains=receiver_company_name)`

And let's assume that I have one company which called for example Dota-2, and when I search in my db this company by typing "D", it's return for me Dota-2.
And my question will be about, if my company "Dota-2" it's saved in db like this "Dota-2", and when I trying to search like this lowercase "d", it's return me empty array. How to make **name_icontains** search by ignoring lower and uppercase letter?

Comment: `name__icontains` is case insensitive while `name__contains` is case sensitive

Comment: Since you're new to this it seems like it is worth pointing out that if you're database is going to have a lot of records to look through this is a very slow way to do this search. It would be much faster to make a `Game` model and then have your records foreign key or many to many onto the `Game` model. Databases are good at searching on keys and bad at doing string comparisons. If this is just a hobby project it won't matter and you'll never notice a problem, but I just thought you should know if you stick with it and go onto larger projects.

Comment: @itzMEonTV I know about that `name__icontains` it's case insensitive, but how to make it's working to russian words???

Answer (score 25):

```
Blog.objects.get(name__iexact=receiver_company_name)
```

you can use `iexact` which takes all the arguments ignoring upper and lower case

or you can use

```
Entry.objects.filter(name__istartswith=receiver_company_name)
```

Comment: I know about icontains work correctly, but how to make it work with russian letters?

Comment: if your database is having russian letter then simply pass russian letter in incontains too, it will works as intended

Comment: istartswith is used to query for fields that starts with the word.